# Redirect based on user and current page functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

I'm looking for a piece of code to add to my wordpress site to redirect certain users based on their role but only when they get to a certain page.

I need this to show a specific page to a specific user role and not the one others get. A plugin won't do in my scenario.

I'm not just looking for a redirect in php. 
I need to make something that will work in 3 steps:

First I need to check if the user/visitor is on the desired page.

After that I need to check for a specific user role (I got this covered).

And at last to redirect (got that coverd to).

I have no idea how to accomplish the first step inside the functions.php and if my flow even makes sense..

Edit: Solved!

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_user_role'); 

function redirect_user_role()
{ 
    if(current_user_can('subscriber') && is_page(' ID, Slug or name here ')) 
    { 
        wp_redirect('https://www.example.nl'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you add some code to what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Below a sloppy piece I tried to redirect on a certain page which did nothing sadly. 

This probably because I'm not calling home in the correct way. However, I have no clue how I should call it..

`<?php if ($pagenow == 'home.php') {
wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit;
}
?>`

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor It's not. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get role of user,

```
  <?php
    global $current_user, $wpdb;
    $role = $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities';
    $current_user->role = array_keys($current_user->$role);
    $role = $current_user->role[0]; //user role
    $page_title = $post->post_title; //get title  f page
    if($role=='subscriber' &&  $page_title=="aboutus") // compare
    { 
         wp_redirect('http://www.google.com'); //navigate if so
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: This code seems to be perfect, however.. To make this fit the functions.php, shouldn't this be inside an action hook? And if so do you have any idea where what $tag to use?

For example: `add_action('$tag', 'redirect_user_role');`

Comment: add_action('template_redirect', 'hooker');
function hooker(){
    //I load just before selecting and rendering the template to screen
}

Comment: Final code I used:

`add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_user_role');

function redirect_user_role(){

    if(current_user_can('subscriber')  &&  is_page(' ID, Slug or name here '))
    { 
         wp_redirect('https://www.example.nl');
    }
}`

Comment: are you get an output